# Amazon Linux 1 yum repo updates beyond 2018.03

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, openssl, yum

In the unfortunate position where ideally, we'd like to update a handful of packages on a legacy deployment of Amazon linux ami 1 with yum configuration set to `releasever=2018.03`. I did try modifying this to `latest` and re-running `yum update` this did not yield any different results.

It would appear packages such as `openssl` have since been patched and I should be able to upgrade the package.

On the EC2 instance I see `openssl-1.0.2k-16.153.amzn1`

It would appear there is a fix available `openssl-1.0.2k-16.159.amzn1`

However, the yum repos seem to be frozen in time and not receiving updates. Does anyone know if i can obtain this automatically from yum without manually installing?

Amazon states that Amazon Linux AMI will receive security patches through June 2023. So this should be possible.

What am I missing?